# Решение капчи на python selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Делаю скрипт на с использованием selenium
На этапе подтверждения номера телефона на сайта openai/chatgpt всплывает капча, причём не зависимо от автоматизации, при ручной регитсрации тоже появляется.
Но с подобной капчей не встречался ранее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь встречал подобную? Можно ли как-то это решить?

Comment: Можно, компьютерным зрением и сопоставлением количества найденных объектов. Учитывая, что они одинакового размера можно даже обойтись без ML и нейросеток.

Comment: А если они не всегда одного размера?

Comment: @ПавелДмитриев что находится под кнопкой аудио?

Comment: @ПавелДмитриев всё равно реализуемо. Но вопрос зачем вам это, если капча появляется только при регистрации?

Comment: Под кнопкой аудио, проигрываются короткие аудио дорожки, где звучат цифры, и два варинат, лио перечислить эти цифры
И второй, пример: назвать цифру, в которой эмитируется жужжание пчелы. И так 4-5 раз
И если всё ок то получаешь смс код, если на каком то шаге ошибка, то сначала всё

Comment: Это нужно для массовой регистрации аккаунтов.